# PGFPlot axis scale

Tags: latex, axis, pgfplots

i want to plot a time signal plot and i have problems with the correct tick label style:

here is my code:

```
    \begin{axis}[
        yscale=0.5,
        ymin=0,
         yticklabel style={scaled ticks=false,
                                 /pgf/number format/precision=1},  
        \addplot[red, solid] table[x=time,y=a]{};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[pfgplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNaGD.jpg)

i tried a long time with pgf/number format/... but i didnt get any usefull help.
what i try is to get is:

1. comma instead points asa decimal
2. at the x axis there should be like 10, 20.. because i want it label with "mV"
3. how i can get for an logarythmic frequency plot a axis tick style like: 1k..1M..1G

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] and only ask one question per question